# The $bin/gora file is not running it always says in cmd "it is not recognized as internal or exernal comand'

Tags: gora

I am new to Apache gora.Just installed it an build it by maven (mvn clean install as in doc). After that i was trying to compile gora-turoial module(It is the example included with the dowloaded project.)

But when i try to run  apache-gora-0.8/bin/gora goracompiler gora-tutorial

it sas 'gora is not recognized as internal or external command'.
[These are the modules in apache-gora-0.8 project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2j58.png)

Answer (score 0):

`bin/gora` command script is designed to be run in a Linux environment, not in a Windows one.

I have created an issue in the [Apache's Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GORA-562) to add a script executable under Windows. Thank you!

Comment: @AhamdNadeem, My pleasure :) Accept the answer/vote up if you consider it the right answer, thanks!